# Get the maximum and minimum value of dimensions in a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a file that is formatted as follows:

Each bag is one line.

The line begins with a label for the bag, which is 0 or 1.

Then there is a tab, and the number of points in the bag.

This is followed by a space, then for each point a list of the values for each of the 8 dimensions of the point.

For example,

```
label    npx x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x21 x22 x23 x24 ...
label    npy y11 y12 y13 y14 x15 x16 x17 x18 y21 y22 y23 y24 ...
```

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum value for each of the eight dimensions across all the bags.  That is, ignoring the label and npx columns, the maximum and minimum value from the 1st, 9th, 17th, 25th, 33rd, 41st, ... columns, the maximum and minimum value from the 2nd, 10th, 18th, 26th, 34th, 42nd, ... columns, etc.

There are different numbers of points in each bag but each point always has 8 dimensions.

I'm sure you can do this with some Unix tool but I don't know enough about those to be able to confidently do it.   How do you go about getting this information?

Comment: What are your thoughts on how to do this? This isn't a trivial task, so you should show some effort. Perhaps you can break this down into several smaller tasks and ask about one of those--e.g., "How can I read the values into an array?" or "How can I loop over every 8th element of an array?"

Comment: Please be more specific, if you show expected output as well along with your input, it would be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not robust (the file must not have any blank lines at the beginning, for example) but should get you started:

```
awk '
    NR==1{for(i=3;i<=10;i++) max[ i % 8 ] = min[ i % 8 ] = $i }
    {
        for(i=3; i<=NF;i++) {
            if(max[ i % 8 ] < $i)
                max[ i % 8 ]=$i
            if(min[ i % 8 ] > $i)
                min[ i % 8 ] = $i
        }
    }
    END { 
        for(i=0;i<8;i++) printf "max in position %d: %d\n", i+1, max[(i+3)%8]
        for(i=0;i<8;i++) printf "min in position %d: %d\n", i+1, min[(i+3)%8]
    }' input-file
```